# How to convert the timestamps (created_at) in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

Hey how do i convert this: `2020-08-04 T13:31:44.342Z`  to this: 2020-08-04 in rails 6? i can not really find the answer to this one because all the answers are aged up, not reliable.

I am reffering to that created_at in my Vue front-end app.

So what should i add to my migration to show like this or is it something that i should manage in my front-end??

my createData migration:

```
class CreateData < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :data do |t|
      t.float :temperature
      t.float :windspeed
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe it will be better convert data in the serialization or `to_json` method? Do you use something like that?

Comment: Please don't mess with how Rails handles `created_at`, this is something you have to handle in your frontend or in the way you return your api data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it'd be easier to just manage the date in your front-end using, for example, JavaScript's `substring`.

`"2020-08-04 T13:31:44.342Z".substring(0, 10) // "2020-08-04"`

Answer (score 3):

I would advice keeping rails timestamps as is. They represent timestamp of creation and updation and should be a `DateTime`. How you want to present your data in web is your frontend property.

In vue, you can pass the timestamp across a filter.

Check [`vue-moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment). It provides you filter over popular moment's library which you can use to play around the timestamps in your desirable format.

```
<span>{{ created_at | moment("YYYY-MM-DD") }}</span>
```